# How to color markers based on polygon area?

Tags: google-maps, polygon, area, color, markers

I have a map with around 317 markers and each marker is the center point of a polygon. The polygonal area varies throughout, so I want to represent the markers in such a way that the polygon with the least area has the lightest shade of the marker color and the marker representing the largest area has the strongest shade of the same marker color.

Can I dynamically produce such colored icons on google maps api??

Comment: Do you have access/familiarity with GIS software such as ArcGIS, QGIS, Manifold, etc.?  Also, what format are these markers and polygons in?

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly Google Maps API that lets you do dynamic pinc coloring but the Google Image Charts API.

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=|B89A00
```

Try the above link for example. That will give you a nice basic teardrop pin, having the color specified at the end of the URL. After you are done with this you can assign the generated URL to the marker of your choice out of your 317 distinct markers.

I hope this helped!

Tamas